# How can I make a CA certificate with `certtool`?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, x509

I can make a self-signed CA certificate with the `openssl` command by putting the line `basicConstraints = critical,CA:true` in the appropriate section of a configuration file and using it:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -config myconfig.cnf ...
```

But I'm having difficulty doing the same thing using the `certtool` command instead.  It seems like I should be able to add the same line to a template file passed via the `--template=FILE` switch, but that line isn't recognized.

I found `basicConstraints` is OID number `2.5.29.19` (at oid-info.com), so I should be able to add a line like this: `add_extension = "2.5.29.19 critical,CA:true"`.  But that fails too.  Apparently the parameter after the OID must be numeric.

Looking at the codes on page 119 of [RFC2459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459), I thought this string might work.  The syntax is accepted, but still doesn't produce a CA: `add_extension = "2.5.29.19 0xff010103300504ff0101"`

So how can I make `certtool` insert extension `critical,CA:true` to create a CA certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactively, when running `certtool --generate-self-signed …`, you just answer positively to the question `Does the certificate belong to an authority? (y/N)`.

In the template, you can add the `ca` key, as the man page says:

```
# Whether this is a CA certificate or not
ca
```

Comment: Good grief.  So simple.  It works.  I looked at that many times.  I wonder why I didn't see.